# Chaining this effect sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This is probably really simple to do. Everything works, this is a horizontal slider that slides one image after another. The issue is, one image slides up, but once that image has slide up, then starts the previous one. My questions is. How do you chain this so that one, slides up but you see the other slide up after the last one.

This function moves the completed slide at the end of the last LI.

```
function cloneView(){

$('.complete').each(function(){
$(this).clone().insertAfter('.slide_img ul li:last').addClass('slides',function(){
    //$('.slides').css({display : "block"});
                            }).removeClass('complete');
$('.complete').first().remove();
  });

 }
```

This function checks how many LI's there are(totalSlides). It also slidesup the current li and sets it as class="complete" (which is how the cloneView knows to move it).

```
$(function () {
  var slideS = $('.slide_img ul li');
  var comp = $('.slide_img ul li.viewing');
  slideHeight = $('.slide_img').height();
  totalSlides = slideS.length;
  slideLength = totalSlides * slideHeight;
  slideS.addClass('slides').css({
    display: "none"
  });
slideS.first().addClass('viewing').removeClass('slides').css({
    display: "block"
});
slideS.last().addClass('last_img').removeClass('slides');

slideInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $('.viewing').delay(1000).slideUp("slow", function () {
        $(this).addClass('complete').removeClass('viewing');
        $(this).next('li').addClass('viewing', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('slides').effect('slide', {
                direction: 'down',
                mode: 'show'
            });
            cloneView();
        });

    });


}, 10000);
});
```

I plan to turn this into a plugin (even though I am sure there are hundreds of them).
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/LCDXj/1/).

Comment: Dont put next slide in the callback of first, just slide em back to back, line for line. I havn't tested what you've got, but that generally works for me in VERY similar scenarios.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I assume you are saying the $(this).removeClass('slides').effect();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a much easier way of doing what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/LCDXj/3/

Made sure that only the `.current-slide` class is visible via CSS:

```
.slide_img {
    height: 445px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
.slide_img ul li img {
    width: 100%;
}
.slide_img ul li{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.slide_img > ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide_img ul li.current-slide
{
    display: block;
}
```

---

1. Set the first element in the slider to be `.current-slide`
2. Every X seconds, slide the current slide up then append it to the back of
   the list
3. Immediately after queueing up the action to slide the first
   slide up, also queue up the action to slide the next slide in the
   DOM structure down.

---

```
$(function()
{
    var slideS = $('.slide_img ul li');
    slideHeight = $('.slide_img').height();
    totalSlides = slideS.length;
    var imgSize = $('.slide_img ul li img').height();
    slideLength = totalSlides * slideHeight;

    slideS.first().addClass('current-slide');

    slideInterval=setInterval(function()
    {
        slideS.filter('.current-slide').slideUp(function()
        {
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).removeClass('current-slide');
        }).next().slideDown().addClass('current-slide');;
    }, 5000);
});
```

The key thing to note that I am doing that you were not is that I am not waiting for the first slide to finish sliding up to start sliding the next one down.

Additionally, by simply appending the element to the end of the `<ul />` afterwards, we don't need to worry about any kind of fancy cloning.

Comment: Looks good. Checking it with my current setting to see if it breaks anything. Thanks.

Comment: HTML-wise the only thing I changed was I added the missing closing `</ul>` at the end.